# Files are not copied from source to destination in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating Windows form application.I am using folderbrowser, textbox1, button.I creating Folder and sub folder inside the Folder.From textbox1 it is selecting particular folder.Inside my if condition, I am selecting specific folder selected at textbox1 and copy files from target folder.I am copying files and storing it in newly created folder as destination folder(which is sub folder inside folder). It is creating Folder,Sub-Folder but not copying files from target to destination folder.I don't understand what is wrong in my code.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
            FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            folderBrowserDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
            DialogResult dlgResult = folderBrowserDlg.ShowDialog();
            if (dlgResult.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
            {
                textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDlg.SelectedPath;
                Environment.SpecialFolder rootFolder = folderBrowserDlg.RootFolder;
            }
   }


 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

          d();


         }
public void d()
      {
            string s = textBox1.Text;
            string z=@"c:\Users\T\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\PlatG\PlGames\DATA\AMT8-P47\data\AMT8-P47";
            string k=@"c:\Users\T\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\PlatG\PlGames\DATA\GDIV8-P89\data\GDIV8-P89";

            string subFolderZ =@"C:\DATA";
            if (!Directory.Exists(subFolderZ))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subFolderZ);
            }
            if(s==z)
             {
                string subFolderZ1 = Path.Combine(subFolderZ, "AMT8-P47");
                if (!Directory.Exists(subFolderZ1))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(subFolderZ1);
                    string[] dirs1d = Directory.GetDirectories(s, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                    foreach (var dir in dirs1d)
                    {
                        string destinationPath = @"C:\DATA\AMT8-P47";

                        string[] fileList = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*");
                        foreach (string file in fileList)
                        {
                            File.Copy(file, file.Replace(dir, destinationPath), true);
                        }
                    }

                }
              }
             if(s==k)
              {
               string subFolderZ2 = Path.Combine(subFolderZ, "GDIV8-P89");
                if (!Directory.Exists(subFolderZ2))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(subFolderZ2);
                    // string p = textBox1.Text;
                    string[] dirs1dd = Directory.GetDirectories(s, "*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                    foreach (var dir in dirs1dd)
                    {
                        string destinationPath = @"C:\DATA\GDIV8-P89";

                        string[] fileList = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*");
                        foreach (string file in fileList)
                        {
                            File.Copy(file, file.Replace(dir, destinationPath), true);
                        }
                    }
                }

              }
         else
            {
             } 
  }
```

Comment: You have a \\ (double backslash) in `k` just after `PlatG`

Comment: Do the subfolders (C:\DATA\AMT8-P47 & C:\DATA\GDIV8-P89) already exist before hand?

Comment: subFolderZ is missing a colon (:)

Comment: Run it in a debugger.  There appears to be many problems with this code.

Comment: i removed \\ and put colon(:) but still not working

Comment: you are also getting not a single exception?

Comment: no i am not getting any exception

Comment: From how I read it you are sure that it enters the ifs.....the question is though does it enter the foreach loop where the file.copy is done? can you test with a messagebox there to see if ti is really entered? (btw you should think about redesigning that part of the code anyway as you have completely duplicate code there that could be better used in its own (private) method)

Comment: code is creating folder and sub folder but not copying files from source to destination

Comment: @delta12 that is why I asked if you can put a messagebox right before the file.copy each. I'm not sure if he does really get into the foreach there or not.    MessageBox.Show(file, "Yippieh", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo); File.Copy(file, fil......  to be more detailed there

Comment: Use `Debug.Print` to see: 1)what you get in `string[]`s. 2)Are you going inside of foreach loop. 3)Which path value is being used to copy file from source to destination. Does it really exists?

Comment: are you and dippune1 in the same class or something? Your question is remarkably similar, right down to the poor presentation, to their question here: [Copying data to all subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33955945). Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, along with a clearer explanation of what the code does now and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Comment: yes me and dippune1 are in same project.The module is very big we just presented the current problem and all three controls are interrelated,I checked your profile You have many many time experience than my current  stage.Please edit my code order  to correct format ,Sir I will learn from that.I visited both the page link you provided but didn't understood how much more i need to  minimize it.Folderbrowser part I can exclude I presented for elaboration purpose only. Anyway I asked this because lack of expertise knowledge.Any help in code ,highly appreciable.

Comment: @delta12 what peter meant with the example is that with your code given there should be no problem there. At least if he is getting any files. Also it is best to split the text you write into: What do you have, what do you want what is the (non wanted) result you currently have.    and on to my  question: did you try my or neverhopeless things out? so as can we be sure that the copy command is executed at all (or the array is empty?)?

Comment: @Thomas I am facing power failure currently,anyway I didn't tested your suggestion.waiting power to back.Power will back after 2-3 hour.Entire city power down.The first thing I  want to do, test your suggestion and I am expecting that will solve my problem,update you after sometime

Comment: Yes @Thomas  after creating folder and sub folder it coming out of loop without copying files,actually not executing file.copy command

Comment: @delta12 so in total it is so that fileList is empty if I got you right there? that would mean then that the GetFiles fails. Else the GetDirectories fails. Umh only as a question did you try  once Directory.GetDirectories(s, "*", instead of Directory.GetDirectories(s, "*.*",  ?   (aka the *.* replaced by just *). If it is the worst case scenario it COULD easily be that he looks for directories that have a . inside of them with *.*

Comment: Yes @Thomas I did tried your way and it is failing at this loop foreach (var dir in dirs1d) not going for get files foreach section,meaning GetDirectories is failing.Now it is killing me more this is very simple command to call directories as far as I know.

Comment: @delta12 I guess we found the problem then (made an answer incorporating the proposed changes. let me know if it helps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we found out during the comments your problem seems to be that you don't get the list of folders.

To rectify this the commando has to be changed from:

```
string[] dirs1d = Directory.GetDirectories(s, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

to:

```
string[] dirs1d = Directory.GetDirectories(s, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Furthermore your current code would just give you all files of the sub directories but NOT of the main directory itself. For this you would have to resize the array (a list would be easier but an array is still manageable there. So I will go with what you currently have thus an array). And add the main directory to the list.

To put it all together:

```
string[] dirs1d = Directory.GetDirectories(s, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
Array.Resize(ref dirs1d , dirs1d.Length + 1);
dirs1d[dirs1d.Length - 1] = s;
foreach....
```

One thing of note for getting the files:

```
string[] fileList = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*");
```

is fine but in case you have files wihtout an extension I'm not 100% that it works. Thus I would also change this to just * like for the folders. Just to be on the save side.

Comment: I implemented your logic and your code is copying file but it is copying files from one directory to  both the directories.Say I select path of 1st directory it is copying files from that directory and putting it on 1st & 2nd directory.Was it possible it copy only 1st directory and put it on 1st directory only.debugging is showing me it is selecting both folder.

Comment: what do you mean with 1st and second directory?

Comment: 1st directory \DATA\AMT8-P47 and 2nd directory DATA\GDIV8-P89

Comment: So to get it right. you have selected for example DATA\AMTO8-P47 folder (the first 1) then it does everything inside the 1st if and then also moves into the 2nd if statement?

Comment: yes,It is moving to second if not copying from second folder rather putting content of 1st to this 2nd folder,& if I select  DATA\GDIV8-P89 it  does  everything inside the 2nd one and moving to 1st folder and putting content of 2nd folder to first one also.Overall It is copying one folder content and putting everything on both the folder .

Comment: CAn you try to replace s==z  by s.Equals(z)  and s==k by s.Equals(k) if that changes anything there? (that he goes into both ifs is strnage but I've seen time and again problems come up with the == comparison and strings, .Equals correctified that always)

Comment: As a note if you have different cases (z Z as example) it can be taht you should use .ToLower()  on the strings each.  thus s.ToLower().Equals(k.ToLower())

Comment: so if you debug through even with equals he enters both ifs?

Comment: yes while debugging also it is going through both loops

Comment: hmmmm are you sure that its the same go through through the method? (as s == z and s == k can't be true at the same time and neither of the 3 is modified aside form once in the beginning of the method it makes no sense that the program uses both ifs)

Comment: please implement same three controls FolderBrowserDialog,textbox1and 2buttons copy paste my code + your section if it is running at your end well than something wrong with my compiler, just calling same files is no sense to me ether putting it on if condition is baseless for me too

Comment: your answer helped me my mistake,i did not noticed b4 executing string[] fileList = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);